Measurement model for ultrasonic sensor (SLAM)
I have a task that sounds like this: “Implement terrain mapping by a mobile robot using two ultrasonic sensors and four wheel encoders.” To do this, I use the SLAM method on ROS Melodic and the Gmapping package. I solved the problem that Gmapping only accepts LaserScan messages and only from one sensor. However, I still can’t figure out how to get Gmapping to build a map based on the readings of ultrasonic sensors. As I understand it, for this need to implement a separate node with a measurement model for these sensors. Has anyone done something similar? I need help with this problem and if anyone can suggest a solution, I will be immensely grateful.
What I want to do is described here in chapters 3.3-3.4, but I don’t understand how this is implemented for Gmapping: https://lup.lub.lu.se/luur/download?func=downloadFile&recordOId=9024868&fileOId=9024869
This is what my robot model looks like: 
